# WCF throwing exception (deserialize parameter) on getting a response

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, serialization, aramex

I'm getting the following exception when I try to get a response from the Aramex API:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/:ProcessedPickup. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 770. 'Element' 'LabelFileContents' from namespace 'http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/' is not expected. Expecting element 'LabelURL'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

The exception details are:

```
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException was caught
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/:ProcessedPickup. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 770. 'Element' 'LabelFileContents' from namespace 'http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/' is not expected. Expecting element 'LabelURL'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
  Source=mscorlib
  Action=http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher/fault
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameter(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameters(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo[] parts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message message, Object[] parameters)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.AfterReply(ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at ServiceReference1.Service_1_0.CreatePickup(PickupCreationRequest request)
       at ServiceReference1.Service_1_0Client.CreatePickup(PickupCreationRequest request) in c:\Users\mohib\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\downloaded_svn\4c9b6bfe\5cf22eca\App_WebReferences.aosg9csc.0.cs:line 2931
       at WES_Pages_Warhouse_new_orders_process.InvokeAPI(String location, Int32 Order_Id, Int32 no_of_shipments) in c:\Users\mohib\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\Downloaded_SVN\WES_Pages\Warhouse_new_orders_process.aspx.cs:line 1340
  InnerException: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
       HResult=-2146233076
       Message=Error in line 1 position 770. 'Element' 'LabelFileContents' from namespace 'http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/' is not expected. Expecting element 'LabelURL'.
       Source=System.Runtime.Serialization
       StackTrace:
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ThrowRequiredMemberMissingException(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 memberIndex, Int32 requiredIndex, XmlDictionaryString[] memberNames)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.GetMemberIndexWithRequiredMembers(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlDictionaryString[] memberNames, XmlDictionaryString[] memberNamespaces, Int32 memberIndex, Int32 requiredIndex, ExtensionDataObject extensionData)
            at ReadShipmentLabelFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
            at ReadProcessedShipmentFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
            at ReadArrayOfProcessedShipmentFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
            at ReadProcessedPickupFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name, String ns)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
            at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.PartInfo.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, XmlObjectSerializer serializer)
            at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
       InnerException:
```

I'm filling in the data exactly as mentioned in their manual. Further, this was working before and I was able to get a response with the desired fields. Now it stopped working. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Look like the data contracts properties might have Order defined which mean the serialized message should be in same order as defined on contract. Can you confirm that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you talking about the order in which I fill the data in my code. If it is so, then how does it matter, because all the required fields will be filled prior to invoking the API.